# What option will make the Grep command to search from bottom-top?

Tags: linux, terminal, grep

Grep's --max-count option starts the search from the top of the file and stops when the phrase had occurred for max-count times. Now, I need to find out the last n occurrences of a phrase?

how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tac` to reverse order of lines (or `tail -r` if your `tail` supports this):

```
tac your_input_file | grep --max-count=N search-phrase
```

Comment: hmm.. afaik only BSD `tail` has the `-r` option, `tail` provided by `GNU coreutils` doesn't.  Moreover, the size of the files BSD tail can reverse are constrained by the size of its buffer. `tac` is better suited to reverse a file.

Comment: @devnull Yes, this is perfectly correct, and I overlooked the 'linux' tag in the question. So `tail -r` is not an option here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with grep alone but you can use tac to reverse the file first:

```
$ tac file | grep --max-count=N foo
```